# Sever unstable ? Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown

Tags: centos

Good day,

We have a new server running
It's a dedicated clean install of:

- centos 6.6 with plesk 12 installation
- Running a intel i7
- with 64 gb of ram

Only 1 magento installation running with around 400 unique visitors daily and 7.000 products in 1 storeview.

Since a few days the server runs smooth for hours, but al of a sudden we get underneath error on almost each pageview, often some visitors can reach the server fine and other not.

When i change the php type from fcgid to apache module or other way around its solved for another 30/40min.

Anybody any idea how to solve this properly

By the way server running ok, with idle cpu time left on the system resources and enough free ram.

```
[Tue Mar 24 11:53:26 2015] [error] [client 207.46.*.*] PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Mar 24 11:53:29 2015] [error] [client 157.556.*.*] PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Mar 24 11:53:32 2015] [error] [client 207.466.*.*] PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Mar 24 11:53:36 2015] [error] [client 157.556.*.*] PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Interesting article here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485371/baffled-php-fatal-error-exception-thrown-without-a-stack-frame-in-unknown-on-l - one likely cause is disk being full.  Depending on your set up, this could be tempfs/sessions/cache folders filling?

Comment: Thank you @DouglasRadburn for your response. but no, disk is not full. either is apc cache or db cache. 

/dev/sda3        78G   35G   40G  48% /
tmpfs            32G   12K   32G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2       504M   39M  440M   9% /boot

Comment: Is this all you get for errors even from the error_log?